# How do I make this loop such that the output is the same as the input unless i press "end" then the programme ends?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

Hi I am new to java programming and I have this code and I want to know how to make it run until i type "end" then it stops. 
Can anyone help? I keep getting an error

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    String code_trigger_starter_str = "start";
    String code_trigger_ender_str = "end";
    //boolean program_running_bool = false;

    Scanner kybd_inpt = new Scanner(System.in);
    String kybd_input_str = kybd_inpt.nextLine();


    re_run_word_input(code_trigger_starter_str,code_trigger_ender_str);

//  exit_code(code_trigger_ender_str);

    }


private static void re_run_word_input(String code_trigger_starter_str,String code_trigger_ender_str) {
    //boolean program_running_bool = true;

    System.out.println("Enter a word");
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
    String kybd_new_word = kybd.nextLine();


    //if(kybd_input_str.equals(code_trigger_starter_str));{

    //System.out.println(kybd_new_word);


        if(!kybd_new_word.equals(code_trigger_ender_str)) {
        System.out.println(kybd_new_word);
        }
        else {
            if   (kybd_new_word.equals(code_trigger_ender_str)) {

            System.out.println("Program ended");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error? (append it to the question)

Comment: it works fine but I need it to run in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works. I used a do while loop.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class WeekendAssignment {

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    //Initialize start and end variables
    String code_trigger_starter_str = "start";
    String code_trigger_ender_str = "end";

    // receive start input in string kybd_input_str
    Scanner kybd_inpt = new Scanner(System.in);
    String kybd_input_str = kybd_inpt.nextLine();


    //using do-while loop to run the method continuously
    do {
    re_run_word_input(code_trigger_starter_str,code_trigger_ender_str);
    }
    while (true);


    }

//create a new method to receive new words input and output the new word
private static void re_run_word_input(String code_trigger_starter_str,String code_trigger_ender_str) {

    //Tell user to input a word
    System.out.println("Enter a word");
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
    String kybd_new_word = kybd.nextLine();

    //set condition using if and else statements

        if(!kybd_new_word.equals(code_trigger_ender_str)) {
        System.out.println(kybd_new_word);
        }
        else {// if user inputs "end" code has to terminate
            if   (kybd_new_word.equals(code_trigger_ender_str)) {

            System.out.println("Program ended");
            System.exit(0);


            }

        }
```